# Does direct file transfer require one of the parties to have a publicly accessible IP?

Tags: language-agnostic, networking, file-transfer

I'm building a direct file transfer tool for sharing files between two users.

Is it an absolute requirement for any of them to have a publicly accessible IP in order to establish such connection?

In case I go with an intermediary server, should all traffic go through it, or can it help parties to establish a connection somehow, and the rest of transfer process will be made between them directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not - but it's more reliable if they do.

However, they will still need an intermediary of some kind in order to find each other in the first place.  Once that's happened, you can use [NAT hole-punching](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/) to establish a direct connection.